# Create Account via Lightning Component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning-apps

I've created a Lightning Application that displays the Account Records.I've added a functionality that should create a new Account Record as well.But it is not working as expected,the new record is not created in salesforce. 
Javascript controller code corresponding to create an Account record:

```
createAccount:function(component,event,helper){
    var newAccount=component.find("newAcc");
    var valueName=component.find("inputNameSample2").get("v.value");
    var valueIndustry=component.find("Industryselect").get("v.value");


     var action3=component.get("c.createAccount");
    action3.setParams({
        "paramName":valueName,
        "paramIndustry":valueIndustry

    });
   action3.setCallback(this,function(res){
        var state1=res.getState();
        if(state1=="SUCCESS"){
            document.getElementById("NewAccountForm").style.display="none";

        }
    });
    $A.enqueueAction(action3);

},
```

Apex controller method for creating a new Account Record :

```
         @AuraEnabled
   public static Account createAccount(String paramName,String paramIndustry) {
       Account acc = new Account(Name = paramName,Industry = paramIndustry);
       upsert acc;
       return acc;
   }
```

Component code for form to make a new Account record :

```
<div id="NewAccountForm" style="display:none" class="slds-col slds-col--padded slds-p-top--large">

      <div>
  <div aria-hidden="false" role="dialog" class="slds-modal slds-modal--form slds-fade-in-open">
    <div class="slds-modal__container slds-modal--form" role="document" tabindex="0">
      <div class="slds-modal__header">
          <ui:button label="Cancel" class="slds-button slds-button--brand" press="{!c.hideDiv}"/>
          <ui:button label="Save" class="slds-button slds-button--brand" press="{!c.createAccount}"/>

        <h2 class="slds-text-heading--medium slds-truncate">New Account</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="slds-modal__content">
        <h3 class="slds-section-title--divider">Account Information</h3>
        <div class="slds-form--stacked slds-p-around--medium slds-m-bottom--x-small">

          <div class="slds-form-element">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="inputNameSample2">Account Name</label>
            <div class="slds-form-element__control">
              <input aura:id="inputNameSample2" value="{!v.newAcc.Name}" class="slds-input" type="text" placeholder="Sample Name" />
            </div>
          </div>

          <div class="slds-form-element slds-m-top--medium large">
            <label class="slds-form-element__label" for="select-01">Select</label>
            <div class="slds-select_container">
              <select aura:id="Industryselect" class="slds-select" value="{!v.newAcc.Industry}">
                <option>Select an Option</option>
                  <option>Agricuture</option>
                  <option>Apparel</option>
                  <option>Banking</option>
                  <option>Chemicals</option>
                  <option>Communications</option>
                  <option>Construction</option>
                  <option>Consulting</option>
                  <option>Education</option>
                  <option>Electronics</option>
                  <option>Energy</option>
                  <option>Engineering</option>
                  <option>Entertainment</option>
                  <option>Environmental</option>
              </select>
            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
       </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="slds-backdrop slds-backdrop--open"></div>


    </div>
```

Comment: check if valueName is null or it has value.

Comment: Yeah you were right @Tushar , it is null at the moment.I need to fix it.